# Text formatting in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I need to change the style(i.e font,color and other attributes) of a particular word or line.
I have tried this with **JTextPane** as:

```
textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(start,length,myTextStyle,false);
```

Is there any way to do the same thing with **JEditorPane**.
How can i format a word in **JEditorPane**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to styled document

```
((StyledDocument)editorPane.getDocument()).setCharacterAttributes(start,length,myTextStyle,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTMl or RTF text to format text within a JEditorPane.

There is a good explanation on how to do this @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Answer (score 1):

Mind, the naming, "JEditorPane" is misleading; `JTextPane` is a subclass of `JEditorPane`. So if you want to make your own styled editor, use `JTextPane`.